# Visual Studio won't show the string values in address, specified by label in address box

Tags: assembly, x86, visual-studio-2017

[The image of an IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZGCP.png)

The context is that after typing in greeting1 into the Address Box, it leads me to the address location 0x00000047, and only the questions marks show up. In my understanding, labels defined under the data segments could be used to specify an address location, where I am expecting to see the string values.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't believe an address this low will be used so its understandable to me that you can't view the data.

Comment: I've updated the context of the problem.

Comment: How did you decide that is the proper address? Are you sure it is not an offset from another base address?

Comment: In my understanding, the labels are representations of the address; thus, I thought typing in the label into the address box will direct me to the values I've assigned it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `0x47` that you see is the ascii code of letter `G` so when you've entered the label name it will try to convert it to an address and display it. If you want to see the content of the label try `&greeting1`.

Comment: @dlee67 happy to help. Can you accept this as an answer then?